# Problema ao startar projeto react

Tags: react, npm, yarn

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Galera fiz o clone desse projeto no github, e dei um npm install, ele baixa as dependências, mas quando eu do yarn start para iniciar o servidor, ele me imprime esse erro.

Answer (score 1):

Está atingindo o limite de observadores do seu sistema.
Tenta executar isso:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Acesse aqui para saber mais:

https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details

Obs.: Se você esta usando o `npm install` porque usar o `yarn start`? Usa o `npm start` ou `yarn install`. Isso pode gerar conflito no `.lock`